# Netbeans 6.5.1 + Openfire 3.6.4 Collaboration?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, collaboration, openfire

We are using the collab plugin in Netbeans. Unfortunately the "Service for the developer collaboration XMPP server share.java.net will be discontinued as of April 20, 2009. "

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqShareJavaNet

I managed to install OpenFire 3.6.4 on OpenSolaris 2008.11.

Whatever I do I cant login from Netbeans collab plugin, but getting "Object does not represnt a valid JID"
Server log:

> 2009.05.23 21:41:27 [org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PresenceManagerImpl.userUnavailable(PresenceManagerImpl.java:271)] Error storing offline presence of user:

Little info to find on this topic, other than

http://wiki.netbeans.org/CollabServer

http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/message/190171

Does anyone run successfully Netbeans with Openfire ?

cheers

Comment: btw, I can connect with pidgin to the server.

Answer (score 1):

i think there's a bug somewhere between Openfire and netbeans collab module.
using NB 6.7, Openfire 3.6.4 and postgres 7, i notice there are 2 process trying to provide "presence" function which resulting 2 conflicted database entry in ofpresence table.

one entry which i believe came from netbeans collab connection, contains a user JID required by netbeans, while the other one didn't, this is what i believe the culprit behind the "Object does not represnt a valid JID" error message.

i decided to experiment with deleting all services in Openfire Group Chat tab, and successfully managed to login from my NB 6.7, but no collaborative channel available...

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Install "Search" plugin from the available plugins list in the openfire admin. THATS ALL!
It's even in the link above :)
If it doesn't work, try disabling offline messages.